# Paste from the clipboard into textarea that uses the class 'form-control rte' (Rich Text Editor)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webview2

I am running a script from WebView2 to complete an online form - works great for the standard textarea using...

```
document.getElementById('fname').value = 'SomeName';
```

But will not work with the bootstap editor - sooo, I moved to copy and paste (and given the data is a Word document that would be better). I have tried...

```
let text = navigator.clipboard.readText(); text.then(txt => { document.getElementById('syn').value = txt; });
```

But that doesn't work either.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

=====================UPDATE========

I have also tried this...

```
const paste = document.getElementById('syn'); navigator.clipboard.readText().then((clipText) => (paste.innerText = clipText));
```

...and that too doesn't work.

I checked to see if clipboard access is supported in WebView2 and apparently it has been since [July 2020](https://github.com/webview/webview/issues/403). Perhaps I need to find a way to enable it? Did try pasting to an ordinary textarea that works by just setting the value, but not with pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the editor is from Froala.

Access is view the textarea ID, so setting the value is

```
$('#TextAreaID').froalaEditor('html.set', 'The text I want to add');
```

Hope this helps someone else.